# serialize class as object

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Using JSON.NET - I'm trying to serialize a mass collection of objects that can contain any other object, that can contain any number of arrays of other objects. Upon doing a serialize and deserialize, the data is not typing correctly/being destroyed. Hours of searches later, can't solve.

```
public class SubClass
{
    public string theString;
}

public class MasterClass
{
    public object theObj;
}
```

---

Sample code:

```
SubClass thesubclass = new SubClass(); thesubclass.theString = "TESTSTRING";
MasterClass theMaster = new MasterClass();
theMaster.theObj = thesubclass;

string jsonOut = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(theMaster, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All});
textBox1.Text = jsonOut;
//Out1: {"$type":"WindowsFormsApplication1.MasterClass, WindowsFormsApplication1","theObj":{"$type":"WindowsFormsApplication1.SubClass, WindowsFormsApplication1","theString":"TESTSTRING"}}

MasterClass testMaster = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MasterClass>(jsonOut);
string jsonOut2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testMaster, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All});
textBox2.Text = jsonOut2;


//Out2: {"$type":"WindowsFormsApplication1.MasterClass, WindowsFormsApplication1","theObj":{"theString":"TESTSTRING"}}
```

---

Basically any object past the main object is losing it's type. //Out2 should match //Out1, but they never do. Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `TypeNameHandling` setting also when you deserialize:

```
MasterClass testMaster = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MasterClass>(jsonOut, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
```

Comment: Wow, all along... thankyou very much, that solved the problem perfectly. 750mb JSON dump across hundreds of random objects now has all the objects correct everywhere. Will upvote when I have 15 rep

Comment: Glad to be of help ;)